# Вывод чисел в QtextEdit

Tags: qtcreator, ui

на форме есть несколько элементов QtextEdit, в которые добавляются элементы следующим образом:

```
void MainWindow::update (int value, int i, int g)
{
QString tab1 = "  \n";
int n = i;

if (g==1){
 value1 = value*100;

 }
if (g==2){
 value2=value1+value;
 qDebug()<<"value1"<<value1;
 qDebug()<<"value2"<<value2;

 }
if (g==0){
 value1=0;
 value2=0;

 }
QString valueAsString = QString::number(value2);
if (n==0){
 if (value!=115){
         ui->textEdit->insertPlainText(valueAsString);
         qDebug()<<valueAsString;
         if(g==2){
         ui->textEdit->insertPlainText(QString(tab1));
         }
}
}
if (n==1){
 if (value!=116){
         //ui->textEdit_2->insertPlainText(valueAsString);
     ui->textBrowser->insertPlainText(QString::number(value2));
         if(g==2){
         ui->textBrowser->insertPlainText(QString(tab1));
         }
}
}
if (n==2){
 if (value!=117){
         ui->textEdit_3->insertPlainText(QString::number(value2));
         if(g==2){
         ui->textEdit_3->insertPlainText(QString(tab1));
         }
}
}
if (n==3){
 if (value!=118){
         ui->textEdit_4->insertPlainText(QString(valueAsString));
         if(g==2){
         ui->textEdit_4->insertPlainText(QString(tab1));
         }
}
}
if (n==4){
 if (value!=119){
         ui->textEdit_5->insertPlainText(QString(valueAsString));
         if(g==2){
         ui->textEdit_5->insertPlainText(QString(tab1));
         }
}
}
if (n==5){
 if (value!=120){
         ui->textEdit_6->insertPlainText(QString(valueAsString));
         if(g==2){
         ui->textEdit_6->insertPlainText(QString(tab1));
         }
}
}
}
```

Если я использую функцию insertPlainText то перед числом появляется "0", а если setText то не появляется, но мне нужно выводить информацию в стобик, не могу понять откуда 0. Как его убрать? Пробовал передавать в textBrowser, то же самое.
[image: Скрин программы:]

Comment: в qDebug выдаёт число верно

Answer (score -1):

В этой строчке я сам передаю переменной 0. Просто не заметил, что при этом условии вывод всё равно будет выполнятся.

```
 if (g==0){
  value1=0;
  value2=0;

  }
```